# Cancelling a Click event when the click is outside of a GUI's bounds in C#

Tags: c#, forms, events

So I'm trying to create a program that will lock the host computer. The way it works so far is it has a main form, where a password can be created, and the computer can be locked. When the password is created, it's stored in a location within the user's AppData, in MD5.

I have the password creation and checking bits finished just fine, but I can't manage to figure out how to make the lock work the way I want. Normally, the computers this would be run on would be locked via Windows (i.e. WinKey+L), but a need has arisen for monitoring of a different program which will always be running. However, as at times these computers may be in a public place, I am looking for a way to only allow access to input after the user's identity has been verified.

I can prevent the program from being terminated just fine, but it's somewhat problematic to detect clicks and keystrokes outside the GUI's boundaries for me. I tried handling the Deactivate event, but that doesn't work because I can't cancel the click that happens with it. I also tried using MouseMove, but then realized that the event is only raised when the mouse is moved within the form's boundaries. I also tried listening for the Leave event, but that also didn't work.

For keystrokes, I've tried checking a KeyPress event's arguments for `e.KeyChar != '\t' && e.KeyChar != '\r'` (is \r what the Enter key would be?) and cancelling the event, and even just bluntly using the statement `e.Handled = true;`, but that doesn't work either. Either way, I can still alt-tab.

Also, with the issue of keystroke checking, I realize that I can just use a Deactivate check instead, and handle FormClosing as well; however, my Deactivate event handler doesn't work either, where the only code it contains is:

```
this.BringToFront();
this.Focus();
```

At this point, I'm sure what I'm doing for the keystroke and the deactivation handlers are small errors, but I have no idea what to do for the clicking issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about Ctrl-Alt-Del and using the task mgr to kill your app?  If you are trying to prevent the user from using a computer without going through your app, you are going to have a hard time doing everything in C#.  Windows has the ability to setup a kiosk mode or you could replace the GINA with unmanaged C++

Comment: Don't even bother to try this using a simple GUI program - there are many ways to circumvent it. As @JohnKoerner wrote, you should look into GINA / kiosk mode for this. A C#-based approach will be an excercise in futility.

Comment: You cannot lock-down a machine with your own program.  A user always has a way to regain control of the machine.  For obvious reasons.  You'll need to configure the machine to disable this.  Google "enable windows kiosk mode" to find out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a more powerful set of Interfaces that is provided by the operating system.  You can do a platform invocation of these functions, but you have to know how to marshal the API's.  This is because a lot of the libraries that allow you greater control is written in C++.  If you use native C++ it is more natural to invoke these commands, but C++ requires more careful attention and will take longer to learn.

If you are looking to cancel or override keystrokes or clicks, you can do so by using global hooks.  Here's an article about it http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

But it only scratches the surface on the subject. You'll have to learn a bit about windows internals and the windows API.  There are some books on this topic and it is very deep.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into global hooks and using C++ for this.